# Replace specific strings in Wordpress title

Tags: php, wordpress, title, str-replace

I'm trying to replace a string within a Wordpress title.  I need replace **two** specific keywords in the title.  I don't wish to change the title for the whole page only for this specific instance.  I can't seem to get this code to work and I'm not sure how to add addition strings to replace.  Thank you for the help - I'm a PHP novice.

```
<?php
$wptitle = the_title();
$wptitle = str_replace('Download', '', $wptitle);?>            
<?php echo $wptitle; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
<?php
$wptitle = get_the_title();
$wptitle = str_replace(array('REPLACESTRING1', 'REPLACESTRING2'), '', $wptitle);?>           
<?php echo $wptitle; ?>
```

Comment: `str_replace()` accepts accepts arrays as arguments. So, you can do `$wptitle = str_replace(array('REPLACESTRING1', 'REPLACESTRING2'), '', $wptitle);?>`